# How do I drop spots on Google Map in an Android app?

Tags: android, maps

I'm developing an Android application where I want to pin out certain spots/addresses on a google map. I have managed to add point to a mapView using OverlayItem and a Drawable. That works great.

But I have installed an application where the pins/spots are added asynchronously, and it looks like they are dropped from the top of the screen on to the map. Looks really nice.

I think I can manage to code the async functionality using threads, but I have no idea how to implement the "falling" feature... Does anyone have a clue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would seem difficult, unless the map were stationary.

If the map won't be panning/zooming, you could do the "falling" via a `TranslateAnimation`, applied to an `ImageView` that floats above the map (e.g., later child in the `RelativeLayout` that holds the `MapView`). When the animation completes, you'd make the `ImageView` be `View.GONE`, and you'd add the actual marker to the `ItemizedOverlay`.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) showing how to do drag-and-drop of an `OverlayItem` using a similar core concept.